# How to get mysql DB data in MVC programming modle

Tags: php, mysql

In my project, I choose MVC programming mode.

First, I have defined a specific Trade class for fetching data from DB
; The code of Trade.php class is :

```
namespace model;

class Trade Extends \Mysql\Crud {
private $ltb;

public function getLastTradeTime($uid, $ip) {
   //$params = array('uid' => '36998020','ip' => $ip);
   $sql = "SELECT sys_dateline FROM ms_trade WHERE uid=36998020 AND sys_ip='183.62.232.198' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";
   $this->ltb = $this->getDb()->query($sql);
   return $this->ltb;// There is only one return value:1528957574
}

}
```

Trade.php class is extends \Mysql\Crud class.

Crud.php class is for connecting DA, and create,update,delete sql etc.

And I have specially tested each function of Crud.php class successfully.

The code Crud.php class is:

```
<?php
namespace Mysql;
class Crud {

private $db;
protected $fields;
public $variables;

public function __construct($data = array()) {
    if ($this->fields && $data) {
        foreach ($data as $k => $d) {
            if (!in_array($k, $this->fields)) {
                unset($data[$k]);
            }
        }
    }
    $this->variables  = $data;
}

public function setDb($db) {
    $this->db = $db;
}
public function getDb() {
    //connecting function
}

public function __set($name,$value){
    //set value
}

public function __get($name)
{   
    //get value
}

public function save($id = "0") {
    //for saving value
}

public function create() { 
    //for create sql
}

public function delete($id = "") {
    //for delete sql
}
}
```

Now I have 1.php control page for getting data through Trade.php class,

```
$uid = $login_userinfo['uid'];
$ip = getClientIp();
$trade_model = new \model\Trade();
$lastTrade_time = $trade_model->getLastTradeTime($uid, $ip); //the value should be 1528957574
```

But the value of lastTrade is "Array";
It seems nothing wrong. Who can give me a favor.

Comment: What does `print_r($lastTrade_time)` ?

Comment: @ivanivan, Array ( [0] => Array ( [sys_dateline] => 1528957574 ) )

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [sys_dateline] => 1528957574 ) )

Comment: @ivanivan, $lastTrade_time[0]['sys_dateline'] works OK. Thankyou!

Comment: `$lastTrade_time[0]['sys_dateline']` should give you your timestamp. Then convert to whatever format via `date()` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is being returned back to you as a multi-dimensional array, with one element that contains an associative array with one element.

`$lastTrade_time[0]['sys_dateline']` should give you your timestamp. Then convert to whatever format via `date()` etc or use in whatever manner you wanted to.